# How can I access all values from a specific column in tables using linq and Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq

Can someone help me? I want to display all values from a specific column in a combo box using linq. I try to do it but I can't figure it out. I am new to linq and can't find a way to do it

Comment: Do you mean that the combo contains the list of columns and you will pick one and show the values, or that you already know the column you want and you'd like to load the list of its values into the combo?

Comment: i already know the column i just want to display all rows of that column in combobox

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show a list of string product names and be able to retrieve their int id you can for example:

```
combo.DisplayMember = "DisplayColumnName";
combo.ValueMember = "IdColumnName";
combo.DataSource = context.TableName.Select(r => 
  new KeyValuePair<int, string>(r.IdColumnName, r.DisplayColumnName)).ToList();
```

You need to replace TableName, DisplayColumnName and IdColumnName with your actual values.

To get the ID of what the user selected (eg for further db queries) you can:

```
var id = (int)combo.SelectedValue;
```

If you want the string of what the user selected:

```
var s = ((KeyValuePair)combo.SelectedItem).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

this works.

```
       var context = new LoginTest();
        var login = context.SignUps
             .Select(c => new { c.id, c.Name });
        comboBox1.DataSource = login.ToList();
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```